# How to simplify lambda to general python

Tags: python, lambda, expression

I have such lambda:

`pit = lambda p, q, r: min(A[p] - A[q], A[r] - A[q])`

How I can write it on "plain" python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean as a named function? Then you would just use the `def` and `return` keywords

```
def pit(p, q, r):
    return min(A[p] - A[q], A[r] - A[q])
```

Comment: how I can transform this to js?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with javascript. If you have a follow-up question, feel free to post a new question to Stack Overflow. (Though you should note that "translate this code snippet for me" is not often well-received, unless you show that you have tried to do so yourself first).